# Backbone fetch collection but it won't save

Tags: backbone.js

I'm building file browser with backbone and heave problem with saving fetched collection. JSON response from server is triggered and looks like this:

> [{"name":".","type":"d"},{"name":"..","type":"d"},{"name":"bolt","type":"d"},{"name":"crm","type":"d"},{"name":"crm_backup","type":"d"},{"name":"parse.php","type":"f"},{"name":"places.txt","type":"f"},{"name":"pyrocms","type":"d"},{"name":"test.php","type":"f"},{"name":"time_test.php","type":"f"},{"name":"wordpress","type":"d"}]

I've checked parse in my collection and it has 11 elements. but when I output my collection it's empty. Here is collection code:

```
var File = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults: {
    'name': '',
    'type': 'f'
    }
});

var FilesCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: File,
    url: '<?php echo site_url('files/dir/'); ?>',
    parse: function(response) {
    console.log("In prase " + response.length);
    return response[0];
    }
});

var files = new FilesCollection();
files.fetch({data: {dir: '/home/stamp/public_html/'}}, {rest: true});
console.log(JSON.stringify(files));
```

Answer (score 1):

The `fetch` is async function. You should call `console.log` in the `success` handler of `fetch` so that you can see output after the data is loaded.

```
file.fetch({
    success: function() {
        console.log(...);
    },
    ...
})
```

BTW, according to the [doc](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-fetch), `Fetch` should only take 1 argument as a hash:

> collection.fetch([options])

Answer (score 0):

From the [fine manual](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-parse):

> **parse** `collection.parse(response, options)`
>
> [...] The function is passed the raw `response` object, and should return the array of model attributes to be added to the collection.

Looks like your `response` is exactly the array of objects that your collection wants to see but you're returning a single object:

```
return response[0];
```

The collection will be looking for an array, won't find one, and the result is that your `fetch` call does nothing. Your `parse` should probably return the whole `response` as-is:

```
return response;
```

Or, if you don't need it for debugging, just drop the `parse` method from your collection, the default implementation should be sufficient for your needs.

Comment: It won't work. I've checked your answer from different question. Which by the way is the same as this one. Without response it won't work either.

Comment: What exactly does `response` look like inside `parse`?